# Sending email without using CRON

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I recently upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9.2 .

I understand that i will need to set up a cron task to send my emails.

However , i am unable to do so via my basic shared hosting account.

Is there a way i can send my mail without downgrading and without using CRON ?

Comment: You can create a module. To manually to that. Create a button at the backend pointing to an admin route which then will trigger the Module with the sending functionality.

Comment: Ask you hosting provider to setup cron.

Comment: Asked but was asked to upgraade